# Understanding Peaks and Valleys in CCF Results

Tags: cross-correlation

I am new to cross-correlation and I'm running an analysis where I'm trying to see if Mentions_t can predict Calls_t at a later date (lags are in days). I got the following results and I am having trouble understanding why my results move in and out of significance so erratically, and what it could mean. Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm concerned that the strange pattern may be indicative of some violated assumption in the model. Or possibly that my results are just white noise that I shouldn't try to draw conclusions from.